# Rails 3 - view in subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller called `dashboard` which has a method `foo`. Now I need a method `bar` that has its view in `dashboards/foo/bar.html.erb` - how do I write that in my `dashboards_controller.rb`?

The structure:

```
- app
|_ views
|__ dashboard
|___ index.html.erb
|___ edit.html.erb
|___ foo/bar.html.erb
|___ foo/foobar.html.erb
```

My code so far

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # do something
  end

  def edit
    # do something
  end

  def foo
    # do something
  end

  def foo/bar
    # doesn't work
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map any route to any controller action you want, but you can't have a controller action with a slash in it:  it's just a ruby method, and slashes aren't allowed in method names or variable names - you'll need to call the method something else, but you can keep your route.

If this is just a one-off then you can make a single custom route for it:

```
#in config/routes.rb
get '/dashboard/foo/bar', to: 'dashboard#foo_bar'
```

To render a particular template, then use the `render :template` command in your controller action.

```
#in the dashboard controller
def foo_bar
  #your code here
  render :template => "/dashboard/foo/foobar"
end
```

(Disclaimer - i may have got things slightly mixed up due to all the foo/bar/foobar action but hopefully you get the idea)

However, it *looks* like you are building a nested section of your website, ie a nested set of controllers and views under a common path fragment.  This is commonly seen with "/admin/:controller/:action" type of routes, where you have a whole admin set of controllers and views.  If this is the case then have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, particularly the "Controller Namespaces and Routing" & "Nested Resources" sections.

Comment: thanks, I did miss the forest for the trees - did not even think of routes here...